# Vertically Aligning Text & Image

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

Im developing the "features" section of a website and Im having trouble aligning text to an image.

I've tried setting the alignment to middle for the image in the css file like this:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

And used `<span>` to place the text, but thats not working either.

What Im trying to acheive is very simple, but none of the solutions I've come across on here or through youtube have worked so I figured that I should just post the code, along with the image of how its supposed to look.

**Heres a link to the folder containing the code:** https://github.com/developedbyv/testing

Inside the folder, theres an image of how the website should look right below the index.html file

I would love any assistance on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part of your site?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Its the features section that has the images of the laptop and the text on the right

Comment: @TylerH not really because their solutions didnt work

Comment: @Vandal I do not believe that you tried all of the solutions there and had no luck. Respectfully, the "how to align X [with Y]" CSS question has been asked on this site *thousands* of times. There are only so many ways to do it, and the 6 or so canonical questions all offer the same group of solutions. If you really believe that your scenario is different, then at the very least we will need to see a [mcve] in your post (rather than a link to a GitHub repository).